# How to build libsvm-3.18 using mingw for Qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use libsvm 3.18 in Qt creator. I've included svm.h in my main.cpp file but I can't use functions like svm_train because when I try to build I get an undefined reference error. I also tried creating a new project in Qt creator and using Import Existing Project then building the libsvm files, but when I run my program, it crashes and gives me a segmentation error during debugging. I've also tried using mingw32-make in the libsvm directory in the command prompt, but I get `process_begin: CreateProcess<NULL, uname, ...> failed` and my project also crashes. How do I make libsvm work in Qt?

Comment: Copying svm.h and svm.cpp into your project works well so I guess there is no more need to build it.